# Convert field types in GDB with Python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, convert, fields-attributes, feature-class

I want to create a python script (ArcGIS 10.1) where I loop through a GDB with several feature classes  and select all the fields which are of text type and convert them to float type. I always want to skip the first 10 and last 2 fields of each featureclass as they actually are supposed to be of text type. I am not quite sure how to do so.. I guess FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion does the trick but I am a bit lost.<

I asked the same Question on Geonet: https://geonet.esri.com/message/527269#527269

This is as far as I got:

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True


# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "D:\Test\2011_LongNames.gdb"


inFeatures = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*")
outLocation  = "D:\Test\FLOAT.gdb"
outName = ??? same as inFeature


field_mapping = ???? part where it converts text fields to float fields

listFCs = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(env.workspace)]
listFCs = listFCs[10:len(listFCs)-2)]


for fc in listFCs:
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(inFeatures, outLocation, outName, field_mapping )
```

Comment: You can't really convert a field, you can add a new one and calculate it... be careful converting text to float. With a field mapping object you can change a field type but I *really* don't recommend doing it that way. The safest way would be to add new fields (float), calculate the text carefully (with an update cursor perhaps) to float, create a new feature class then append with field mapping the new float fields and skip the existing text fields.

Comment: oh ok, the field mapping thing somehow seems to be the fastest solution to me, why do you not recommend it?
and how would you get started with the solution you suggest? (I am not very good with python)

Comment: Converting text to a float (or int or date) is *theoretically* straightforward but in my experience there's usually a few double dots, other characters or "" fields that cause the conversion to fail. The quickest and nastiest solution is to export the attribute table to text and import with Microsoft Access and specify the field as float, that way the failures end up being a log rather than 'I can't do this' error message.

Comment: never worked with Microsoft access but I can give it a try. Is this doable with a script as well? (As I have many tables)
Actually my data is pretty clean, the text values are all "numbers"

Comment: If your data is clean then this should be quite straightforward (about 5-6 lines of code) and fast using arcpy.da.UpdateCursor and wrapping a `float` function around the strings you get from the text field.  I think you should do that in a test script separate from the code that you have presented so that you gain that important skill before trying to integrate it back into your main code.

Comment: can you give me a second hint? I am really a bit lost on how to create that sort of script

Comment: It's very similar to both examples in the help for [arcpy.da.UpdateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000) although I think the second one will be the easiest to adapt.

Comment: ok thanks, I couldn't make it work but I ll post an update when I (ever) manage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with @PolyGeo. I think your approach of using field mappings is the best approach, assuming the structure of all 100 tables are identical. Here's an example of how you may create your field map:

```
  fms = arcpy.FieldMappings()  
  fms.addTable(fc)  
  nfields = len(arcpy.ListFields(fc))  
  # skip fields 0,1 (OID, Shape), next 10, and the last two  
  for fi in range(2 + 10, nfields - 2):  
    fmap = fms.getFieldMap(fi)  
    ofield = fmap.outputField  
    ofield.type = "Double" # change from String to Double  
    fmap.outputField = oField  
    fms.replaceFieldMap(fi, fmap)
```

Comment: Thank you! The code worked when I tested it on a GDB with 2 feature classes, however I completed the process in FME as I have different field names in all FC and couldn't find it out how to do it with a script on time! Will definitively use it in the future though!

Comment: If you have FME ($$) I understand it's a much better tool for this kind of "data rescue". Glad you were successful getting your data files in shape. We have a license for DataInteroperability (which is an ArcGIS extension interface to FME) and I've heard good things.